# How can I copy an element of an array of chars to a char?

Tags: c

Let's say I've got this piece of code:

```
void copyElement(int n, char source[100])
{
    char s;
    strcpy(s, source[n]);
}
```

I will get some errors and it won't work.

What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: `char s = source[n];`?

Comment: The `str` prefix in `strcpy` is for *strings*, as in null-terminated arrays of characters. Not for single characters, which are really only a small integer. If it was an array of `int` would you still wonder about how to do this?

Comment: And unless your problem really involves both C and C++, please don't tag both languages (or other unrelated languages), only add the tags of the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: From the current C and C++ tag moderation guidelines [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info): "If you encounter a post with both tags, edit/re-tag it if needed according to the above rules. If you can tell the language by reading the posted code, simply edit tags accordingly. Avoid prompting the user "is it C or C++?" in comments unless the question is truly unclear."  In this case if you got 2000 rep and know C and C++, simply note the complete absence of C++ in the posted code, click "edit tags" and drop the C++ tag. Goes much faster than writing these "C or C++" rants in comments.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that was the answer. I don't know why I didn't think about that, it was quite obvious :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly. If you want to copy a `char` of a specific position you can use

`char c = source[index_of_array];`

Answer (score -1):

strcpy takes pointers to characters and not characters, what you could do is

```
void copyElement(int n, char source[100])
{
    char * s = (char *) malloc (1) ;
    strcpy(s, &source[n]);
}
```

Comment: `s` is uninitialized, it points to some garbage memory. You can't copy anything there.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you're right I am changing that, thanks

Comment: Major heap overflow. `strcpy` will copy all of the characters from `&source[n]` to `&source[99]`, as `strcpy` only stops when it encounters a null char.